# Locking a custom button size

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am drving from `Button` and I want this new custom button to be always 20 by 20 pixels. I wrote in the default and my own implemented constractor both the `Width` and `Height` to be 20 but this does not change anything if I drag the control from toolbox into designer or I programatically add the control to form.

```
    public partial class PinButton : Button
{
    public PinButtonData Data { get; set; }

    public PinButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Height = 20;
        Width = 20;
    }

    public PinButton(PinButtonData data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Height = 20;
        Width = 20;

        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `SetBounds` method and pass `20` as the height and width parameters in the base call.